# Page Number in middle of paper IEEE Latex

Tags: page-numbering, ieeetran

[image: This is the image]I have a latex document where I have used an appendix. However, the page number in the appendix is in the middle of the page, not at the bottom center as can be seen above.

I have the following two lines only

```
\newpage
\appendix
```

A brief overview is:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{balance}

\begin{document}
\title{ABCD}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{plain}
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{abstract}
Abstract goes here.
\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
ABCD
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\section{Introduction}
This is a paper.

\section{Realted Work}
These are related works.

\section{Methodology}
This is the methodology.

\section{Conclusion}
This is the conclusion

\newpage
\balance
\begin{thebibliography}{00}
bibitem{b1} this is reference
\end{thebibliography}
\vspace{12pt}

\newpage
\appendix

some texts

\begin{tikzpicture}
\end{tikzpicture}

some texts

\begin{tikzpicture}
\end{tikzpicture}

some texts

\begin{tikzpicture}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

What could be the source of error?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please edit your query to post an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) (minimum working example) that replicates the problem behavior you wish to fix. For sure, we need to know which document class you employ. Knowing a bit more about what's on the appendix page -- tables?, figures?, text?, all of the above? -- is likely important as well.

Comment: can you check now?

Comment: Not really. You're still not revealing which document class you employ. Please post a standalone, compilable example that generates the problem behavior you wish to fix.

Comment: I have tried to give an outline now

Comment: Thanks for posting some more code. Unfortunately, it does *not* generate the problem behavior you say you're encountering in your real document. When I compile your code, the page number is at the top right, not in the middle of the page. (This is true even if I replace `\newpage` with `\clearpage` to force a page break. In that case, the page numbers are placed at the bottom of the page, not the middle of the page.)

Comment: But the page number is supposed to be in the bottom center. How to do that here?

Comment: Your latest code isn't compilable since you haven't indicated how or where the macro `\balance` is defined.

Comment: it's \usepackage{balance}

Comment: I tried using ```\clearpage```, but it's in the center of the page

Comment: can you see the above picture? the number 12 is the page number. It's at the center

Comment: Instead really text use some dummy text generated for example with package `lipsum` and show obtained result. The page numbers are on bottom of the page (horizontally centered).

Comment: We fully believe you that you're experiencing an undesirable typesetting outcome; that's not the issue. The issue remains the same: You've got to provide code that actually replicates the problem behavior you need to fix. The code you've posted so far *does not* -- it places the page numbers at the bottom of the page (centered), not in the middle of the page.

Comment: If I use \pagestyle{empty}, the page number vanishes. Do you think it's a better idea to have an appendix without page number than to put it in the wrong position?

Comment: I found the error. If I remove the ```\balance```, my page number goes to the bottom center. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Or another way is to use ```\nobalance``` before the ```\appendix``` command

Comment: `\balance` is not a cause of your problem ...

Comment: When I used ```\nobalance```, it resolved my issue. But when I tried the code I have given before, it worked fine. Maybe I had some typesetting issues with that, as mentioned before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your MWE works fine (after correcting error in bibliography. For confirmation and for your tests I extend your MWE with some dummy text generated by package `lipsum`:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{balance}

\usepackage{lipsum} % added for dummy text in MWE

\begin{document}
\title{ABCD}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{plain}
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[66]
\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
ABCD
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\section{Introduction}
This is a paper.

\lipsum[66]

\section{Realted Work}
These are related works.

\lipsum[66]

\section{Methodology}
This is the methodology.

\lipsum[66]

\section{Conclusion}
This is the conclusion

\lipsum[66]

%\newpage removed, that `\balance` has effect
\balance
\begin{thebibliography}{00}
\bibitem{b1} this is reference % corrected bibitem to \bibitem
\end{thebibliography}
\vspace{12pt}

\clearpage
\appendix
\lipsum[1-2]

    \begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw, align=center] {some\\image};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
some texts

    \begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw, align=center] {some\\image};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}

some texts

    \begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw, align=center] {some\\image};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

In my test I use recent MikTeX, updated few days ago.